# How TeX places text horizontally and vertically?

Tags: boxes, paragraphs, box, structure

Am I right that TeX processes text in a manner like this? Since the very first character it is forming an `hbox` of `textwidth` width. When the first `hbox` is filled in its width, TeX makes a hyphenation, adds this `hbox` to a `vbox` (for a paragraph) and starts to form the second `hbox` and so on. So the `vbox` is like a holder for several `hbox`'es (lines)? Is it like a vertical linked list of horizontal linked lists?

Below is an illustration of what I want to clarify. In the first line it makes an indent and hyphens as ma-chines. In the second one I tried to explicitly represent this. Does TeX do the same (ideologically)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Computer science is the study of algorithmic processes, computational machines and computation itself.

\vbox{%
\hbox{\indent Computer science is the study of algorithmic processes, computational ma-}%
\hbox{chines and computation itself.}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No TeX does not typeset line by line. Once a paragraph starts, horizontal mode is entered and the entire paragrah is set in a horizontal list (similar to an `\hbox`) then the entire paragraph is passed through a line breaking algorithm that does a least cost optimisation trying to minimise badness (actually, demerits) of the paragraph. The resulting sequence of hboxes and vertical glue and penaltiues is then added to a similarly infinite vertical list and later a similar but simpler algorithm splits a page off this main vertical list.

So the end result is similar to what you show but the timing is different.

Comment: So hyphening and line breaking does not interrupt the horizontal mode? It is like a sign of line breaking within the horizontal list?